# Garbage after reading a file with fread

Tags: c

I am reading from a file. Everything in my program is dinamic. So I use malloc everywhere.

User input is read this way:

```
int read_line(char **cad){ 
int size = 0;
char *read=NULL; 
size_t u=0;  
size = (getline(&read, &u, stdin) - 1); 

read[strlen(read)-1] = '\0';
*cad = read;
return size;
}
```

For integers:

```
long int read_number(){
char *cad=NULL;
char *garbage=NULL;
long int option=0;  
if(read_line(&cad) == 0){
    option = -1;
}else{
    option=strtol(cad, &garbage, 10);

    free(cad);
    option = *garbage? -1 : option;
}
return option;
}
```

The fact is that this works perfectly all the time. But after I import data from my file, it stops working.

Here is how I read the data:

```
data = (struct data*)malloc(sizeof(struct data));
res = fread(&data->n1, sizeof(int), 1, ptr_file); 
do{                     
res = fread(&data->n2, sizeof(int), 1, ptr_file);                                   
if(res != 0){
    insert_node(&list, data);
}else{
    ret = -1;       
}   
data = (struct data*)malloc(sizeof(struct data));
}while(!feof(ptr_file) && (res = fread(&data->n1, sizeof(int), 1, ptr_file))!=0);
```

I did the do...while loop like that because I wanted to avoid de iteration were the file is EOF(). I'm pretty sure that the problem is because of that EOF. The file is closed without errors.

**After reading the file, my read_number() function keeps returning -1. I've tried to used fflush, but nothing changes.**

Thanks so much! I tried to put the most important part of the code, the part were the real problem is, but not everything. If you don't understand something just tell me. I've been having problems with this for 5 days.

Comment: What will help you fix it and us to understand this issue is a simple, short program that replicates the exact problem you are having.  This program should just compile straight off and have example input data and example error output

Answer (score 0):

don't use feof(), return value of fread() is enough :

```
do {
.
.
.
} while (fread(...) == number_of_elements) // 0 or a value smaller than number_of_elements means eof or error
```